# Buscar palabras en un texto con javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo varias palabras que tengo que buscar en un texto por ejemplo:

```
var keyswords = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
```

y quiero buscar cada palabra una por una en un texto por ejemplo:

```
esta es un test
```

alguien me puede ayudar en que función usar para hacerlo por favor

Comment: @Juan Salvador Portugal, Buenas tardes!; soy Lcdo Jose Fernando Frugone explícame para poder hacer la búsqueda pero si el párrafo lo extraes de una pagina WEB así en javascript var caja = document.getElementById("parrafo1").innerHTML; por ejemplo

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar search() asi:

```
var str = "Visit W3Schools!";
var n = str.search("W3Schools");
```

En este ejemplo la variable n te retornaria 6 que es el indice donde inicia la palabra que buscaste.  Si no se encuentra la palabra, te retorna -1.

Comment: mmm si es si lo encontre pero necesito buscar palabra por palabra de esta colección:   keyswords = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]

Comment: Simplemente usa un loop

Answer (score 1):

Podes hacer lo siguiente;

```
var keywords = ["test1", "test2", "test3"];
var ejemplo = "Este es el test3 , es un ejemplo";
var resultado = "";
var pos = -1

//uso foreach para recorrer cada elemento del array
keywords.forEach(function(element) {

    //En caso de existir se asigna la posición en pos
    pos = ejemplo.search(element.toString());

    //Si existe
    if(pos!=-1){
    resultado += " Palabra "+element+ "encontrada en la posición "+pos;
    }

});

//En caso de que no exista.
if(pos === -1 && resultado === ""){resultado = "No existe ninguna de las palabras del array.";}
console.log(resultado);
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Estimado @Juan Salvador Portugal, Buenas tardes!; de este ejercicio para buscar una palabra de un arreglo, pero en el caso que buscasemos la palabra dentro del 2 parrafos que extrajemos de una pagina WEB sea la pagina WEB "index.html", el codigo javascript que seria lo siguiente:

```
var criterio = document.getElementById("datos").value;
var cuadro1 = document.getElementById("parrafo1").innerHTML;
var cuadro2 = document.getElementById("parrafo2").innerHTML;
var keywords = [cuadro1.toString(),cuadro2.toString()];
var resultado = "";
var pos = -1;

function validar(){

    // uso foreach para recorrer cada elemento del array
    keywords.forEach(function(element){


        

        //en caso de existir se asigna la posicion
        pos = criterio.search(element.toString());

        

        //si existe
        if(pos!=1){
            resultado += "Palabra " +element+ "encontrada en la posicion "+pos;
            alert(resultado);

        }


    });

    //en caso de que no exista
    if(pos===-1 && resultado===""){
        resultado = "No existe palabra en el array";
        console.log(resultado);
        alert(resultado);

    }

}
```

La búsqueda es igual pero si se extrae de una pagina WEB como párrafo?

Comment: Esto es una pregunta o una respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

- [String.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/includes) para ver si un string contiene un substring.
- [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/some) aplica una función a cada elemento. Si encuentra al menos 1 verdadero, devuelve `true` y deja de buscar.

Para buscar una lista de palabras `arrayPalabras` dentro de un string `texto`:

```
arrayPalabras.some(palabra=>texto.includes(palabra))
```

Ejemplo:

```js
var keywords = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'],
    frase = 'este es un test',
    resultado;

//ejemplo 1 (no contiene)
resultado = keywords.some(palabra=>frase.includes(palabra));

console.log(resultado, 'en', frase);


//ejemplo 2 (contiene)
var frase2 = 'esta frase tiene la palabra "test2" y coincide',
    resultado2 = keywords.some(palabra=>frase2.includes(palabra));
console.log(resultado2, 'en', frase2);
```

Comment: Estimado @Pollo, Buenas noches!, Perfecto realice este cambio que dijiste en el código:  verdad = keywords.some(palabra=>element.includes(criterio)); y funciona pero en el caso de que ingresemos una palabra que no existe igual lo da con resultado de verdad pero esta bien planteado por lo visto.

Comment: Ok! @Pollo realice el cambio que tu pusiste pero a mi código de mi archivo "main.js" (javascript) indicando lo siguiente:  verdad = keywords.some(palabra=>element.includes(criterio)); y si funciona, mi pregunta es y si ingresas una palabra a buscar que no es correcta igual da como resultado un valor de false?

Comment: `verdad = keywords.some(palabra=>element.includes(palabra))` ... tenés que usar "palabra" en `includes()`... es una función que recibe como parámetro esa variable... Edito el código para mostrarte ambos ejemplos